# meta/exif-data from captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection missing

Tags: iphone, ios

When I capture still images with the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` method of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` together with the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, trying to retrieve exif data with `CMGetAttachment` and `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` from the `CVImageBuffer` gives back `NULL`. I especially need the ISO-rating of the last taken photo. How can I retrieve that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that I used `CMGetAttachment` with the `CVImageBuffer`, but I had to use it with the `CMSampleBuffer`.